# Getting 'GET or POST' from url

Tags: php, get

I am setting up a 404 page but i need it to get the value from the address.
What i mean is, if the URL is `localhost/main?var=0`, I want to get the number which is in the URL. So `0` because in the URL it says `var=0`.
I have tried using `$_GET['var']`.

Note, The directory `main` does not exist, because i am using a 404 page to get the information.

Comment: First make sure you have an errorfile defined in you apache / nginx / webserver config. This errorfile should be an php file. In the PHP file you can just use $_GET['Var'] as you already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to catch all parameters even if the called script/page whatsoever does not exist. In order to get this to work with Apache you could set up an error handler in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php
```

You will then be able to read your variables in `404.php` in the following arrays:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD'] # POST
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] # GET
```

Is this what you tried to achieve in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `$_REQUEST['Var']`.
However, I tend to use lower-case variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] and explode to get the id.

```
$get  = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'];
$videoID = explode("v=", $get);
echo $videoID[1];
```